# Android App Opening URL in Chrome Missing QueryString

Tags: android, google-chrome

A client of mine has had an Android app built to interface with the web app I've developing for him.  The app scans an NFC tag, then opens Chrome to the login page of the web app, with ?nfc=blah attached to the URL.  Or that's what it's supposed to do.  For some reason the ?nfc=blah is missing everytime.

When I check the logs on the server, there's always a HEAD request (with the ?nfc), followed by a GET request (with it missing):

```
2016-09-16 15:10:35 MYSERVER HEAD /Login/PinLogin nfc=%3DADM6kDM6YTMgYTMwIzL5AzL2EDNuVmA&X-ARR-LOG-ID=53884df3-1666-4d35-97bb-d54009c4eb05 80 - 82.132.244.94 - - -
2016-09-16 15:10:37 MYSERVER GET /Login/PinLogin X-ARR-LOG-ID=16da179d-3328-4d01-848d-fc38d6f156fd 80 - 82.132.244.94 Mozilla/5.0+(Linux;+Android+4.4.2;+GT-I9195+Build/KOT49H)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/52.0.2743.98+Mobile+Safari/537.36 - -
```

The HEAD request never has a UserAgent either.  Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

The Android app developer has gone AWOL and the client doesn't have a copy of the code, so I'm left trying to figure out if I can solve this one at this end :S

Comment: What you need a token of some sort you can add in the HEAD request and have it come back with the GET request so you can tie the two together calls together. Have you tried setting a COOKIE in the HEAD and reading it in the GET?

Comment: Hi DataDino, thanks, I have tried something similar, using Session variable, just waiting for the client to confirm it's working.  Happy to accept your idea as the Answer if you want to post it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need a token of some sort you can add in the HEAD request and have it come back with the GET request so you can tie the two together calls together.

Try setting a COOKIE in the HEAD and reading it in the GET request so that you grab the query string from the HEAD and return in the GET.